# Using like over charindex to search for pattern

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, pattern-matching

We where using charindex to search for a string as shown below

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE ( Charindex('47a%$.abc',CAST(columnname AS VARCHAR(MAX)))>0 )
```

I am planning to replace charindex with LIKE as i require to search only whether the pattern exists not the position.
So i want to know is these any disadvantage in using LIKE over charindex for my case.I am using charindex in several cases. So i want it to work for all sql datatypes ,all characters including special characters(including % (as like already uses %pattern%).So please tell me is there any disadvantage in using like over charindex

Comment: Have you looked into using full text search?

Comment: @MartinSmith full text search available in express edition?

Comment: Yes. You need to download sql server express with advanced services to get it though.

Answer (score 5):

The disadvantage is that you need to escape all characters of special significance in the pattern syntax.

Following your [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/like-uses-index-charindex-does-not) it seems the way you do the escaping affects the cardinality estimates.

Testing on SQL Server 2008/2012

```
SELECT name
/*Copying into a temp table as on 2012 this table is now in the readonly 
 resource database*/
INTO #T
FROM   master..spt_values
```

Then

```
SELECT *
FROM   #T
WHERE  name LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

gives an estimated row count of `625.33/627.575`. But

```
SELECT *
FROM   #T
WHERE  name LIKE '%[%]%'
```

gives an estimated row count of `1.8563/1.86296`.

In fact no `name` values in that table contain a literal `%` character so the second one *appears* to be more accurate in this case.

The response to [this Connect Item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/680257/optimization-problem-on-a-query-with-two-similar-like-clauses-one-with-a-variable) states

> We do not have support for precise cardinality estimation in the
>   presence of user defined escape characters. So we probably get a poor
>   estimate and a poor plan. We'll consider addressing this issue in a
>   future release.