# How can I improve the performance of where clause with LIKE %abc?

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, select, like

I had below select statement that turned out very slow (41s)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Doc_Resource_ID 
       ,a.Parent_ID 
       ,a.Logical_Path 
       ,a.lvl 
       ,CAST(SUBSTRING(a.Security_Level, 21, 1) AS TINYINT)
  FROM Doc_ACL_Detail_D a   
 WHERE a.UserId = @I_vUserId 
   AND @I_vParentId = 0 
    OR (Logical_Path LIKE(CASE 
                             WHEN @I_vParentId>0 THEN '%-'+LTRIM(STR(@I_vParentId)) 
                          END)
    OR Logical_Path LIKE(CASE 
                            WHEN @I_vParentId>0 THEN '%-'+LTRIM(STR(@I_vParentId))+'-%' 
                         END ))
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5000)
```

I already created a non-clustered index for table `Doc_ACL_Detail_D` but the execution plan is still Table Scan.

The index that I created :

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Doc_ACL_Detail_D_UserId_Logical_Path 
       ON [dbo].[Doc_ACL_Detail_D] ([UserId],[Logical_Path])
  INCLUDE (Parent_ID,Doc_Resource_ID,lvl,Security_Level)
```

Could someone please help me to optimize this statement. Thanks a lots.

Comment: While not able to directly pinpoint an issue, you could look at the actual execution plan (and/or share it so others can look at what your DBMS is actually doing for this query). You can get a visualisation that's shareable through [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Alternatively which can impact performance are your statistics, which might need to be refreshed or are otherwise hampering performance. Grabbing a link from a related question [Wait Satistics](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/)

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46917/like-uses-index-charindex-does-not

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind seeing your query is: are you using local variables?

Cause if you do, you might not get a seek on userId even if it's really selective.

Check this great answer from Erik Darling https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206817/106520

Comment: A trigram index will help, but I don't know how to make one in MSSQL.

Comment: @AndreKR Here's an [example](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) for trigrams.

Comment: Have you updated your index statistics recently?

Comment: What is the definition of `Logical_Path`, `Doc_Resource_Id` etc? Are these small fields or large fields? Query optimisation is about memory usage and disk bandwidth - if `Logical_Path` is `text` that is very different to `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 17):

No index can help with this data as it stands.
The value you are looking for in embedded somewhere inside the field, not at the start of a field (where an Index could help).  Because the database doesn't know what's at the *start* of the field, it can't navigate to the right bits of the index to get to the records you want.

Reversing the value and indexing *those* values would help where the value is at the *end* of the field, but still *won't* help where the value is stuck in the middle, somewhere.

To me, this screams of having "too much" data in this field.  You're using string manipulation functions to extract part of the value, which says to me that the value you actually want is "wrapped" in "noise".  *Getting rid* of that noise might be a far better option.

```
select * 
from Folders ; 

+----+--------+------+
| id | parent | path | 
+----+--------+------+
|  1 |  NULL  | abc  | The folder /abc 
|  2 |      1 | def  |            /abc/def 
|  3 |      2 | ghi  |            /abc/def/ghi 
+----+--------+------+
```

*Much* easier to traverse *this* structure recursively.

Also, consider removing the `distinct`.
All too often, I see distinct used as a "sticking plaster" to cover up an underlying problem with the data structures themselves or with a query, for example "duplicate" rows that appear in the results (usually caused by bad Joins) but "using distinct makes them go away".  Getting rid of those "duplicates" can be a *huge* drain on the database ("select distinct a,b,c,d" can perform as badly as "group by a,b,c,d order by a,b,c,d"), so it's better to fix the root cause.